# How can I open thunderbird in the system tray with a command

Tags: command-line

How can I open thunderbird minimized with a command? `nohup thunderbird &` doesn't work with it, while it works with skype and amarok...

Comment: Doesn't it appear in [under the email menu](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0bzn5.png), or are you using another desktop environment to Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've done.  I've added the Minimize On Start and Close add-on in my Thunderbird:

- Start Thunderbird
- Click on the Tools Menu
- Click on addons
- Click Get addons
- Enter Minimize
- Look for Minimize On Start and Close 1.3.2
- Download and restart Thunderbird

[image]

Once that's done, just add Thunderbird to startup applications, and you're set.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you :)