# Thunderbird/E-Mail icon not showing on Systems-Tray

Tags: thunderbird, email, notification, system-tray

I just set up Thunderbird on my 14.04 system and I remember seeing an E-Mail icon in the Systems-Tray around a year ago. As I didn't need it, I somehow made it go away.

**How do I get an E-Mail Notification Icon for my Systems-Tray to tell me about new Mail?**

I've tried the `MinimizeToTray revived` extension, which does not give me a Tray Icon (, although I think it does keep it running even if clicking to close, when I enable that feature.)

In addition: **How to I set up Thunderbird to start minimized to Tray at startup?**

Comment: Do the opposite of http://askubuntu.com/questions/510663/remove-thunderbird-from-the-indicator-messages/510685#510685, and see if this helps http://askubuntu.com/questions/424555/how-can-i-open-thunderbird-in-the-system-tray-with-a-command/424561#424561

Comment: @Mitch Unfortunately there is no `messages` line under `indicator` for me.

Comment: Messages indicator is part of Unity. If you are not using Unity, please state which environment you use.

Comment: @DanJohansen I use Xubuntu, and I have the message indicator.  See [image](https://copy.com/RP94ax8jNmHSnWfU).

Comment: @DanJohansen I'm using Unity. The MessagingMenu is just simpely gone and I don't know how to get it back.